# Optimizing J48 and CART size

Tags: cart, optimization

I would like to optimize the size of J48 decision tree and CART as well. I use the parameter of M (minimum number of instances per leaf) for J48 in order the control the size. For reaching the required tree size I played with the value M. I would like to know if there are any optimal ways for finding the M value for achieving the required tree size with minimum iterations (different from trial and error)? 
The same question for CART while controlling the minbucket parameter, which is the minimum number of observations in any terminal (leaf) node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cross validation through Caret package in R. In Caret you can choose the best cp( complecity parameter), or minsplit (min numbers per split), etc through cross validation and calling for your final model. you need to use rpart to control for cp and rpart2 to control for minsplit in Caret.

Update:

in rpart package you can directly specify the minbucket value that gurantees minimum number of cases per leaf:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/rpart.control.html

But it is better to choose the best tuning parameter through cross validation:

Min number of instances (samples per leaf) is normally a third of min numbersplit... that is minnumber per leaf= minnumsplit/3 or minsplit= minnumberperleaf *3 - thee are the control funtion for tree algorithm and you can define a range of values to train the model on- here is a link that i think it is a good tutorial on training tree with various tuning:

parameters:https://rpubs.com/chengjiun/52658

In caret you can find the best tree (the tree with the best minsplit or the best cp) which gives you the lowest error or lowest classifications error via cross validation.

If you want to see the number of instances for the final model(best model chosen via cross validation) you can ask for the model summary, or visualize the tree to see the numbers per leaf (if this is what you are after)- there are packages in R which allow for nice visualization of tree.(libraries such as fancyrpartplot and rattle)

Comment: Thanks RomRom, can you please elaborate your answer. I would like to understand if I want to reach a specific J48 size, how does R will find the appropriate (optimal values)? Does it find only the CP or Minsplit or also can find the M (minimum number of instances per leaf) for J48? Is there a difference between CART and J48 for optimization?

Comment: I updated the post above and shared some links and additional information. hope this answers your questions

Comment: Thanks a again, I'm looking for optimization: given the size of tree the system will find the best values for parameters you mentioned.